# how to access keywords in multiple classes at remote side with in single robot script?

Tags: python, robotframework

remote machine can generate the multiple classes.  And how to access different keywords in different classes with in single robot script.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to have a read at [ask] to understand how to improve your question.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia you can just put `[ask]` and it fills in the link for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Riccardo Petraglia and @Peter Wood that your question is shorter than it should be to receive a response, let alone the answer you seek.

That being said, I do think I understand your question. From the [Robot Framework User guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface) it only talks about supporting a single class instance. Although your question doesn't state it, I'm assuming that you're looking into the [Python Remote Server](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer). That being said, it is likely the case for other languages as well.

While going through the issue list, I see that there is an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer) for the support for multiple libraries. In the issue discussion Zimmerman highlighted that his [RobotFramework-tools](https://github.com/zimmermanncode/robotframework-tools) project has a [remote server functionality](https://github.com/zimmermanncode/robotframework-tools#4-using-robot-framework-remotely) that supports multiple libraries. Perhaps adopting this will be the solution you seek.

Alternatively, you can start several servers, each on a different machine or if needed on the same but a different port. Each of these servers can then be imported as a separate library and the keywords can then also be used in a single script.

If you're comfortable with Python development, then creating a [Dynamic Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dynamic-library-api) that exposes all keywords from your libraries as a single virtual library. Although not required, it does help if your keywords are unique across all libraries. An example can be found below:

Robot File: note that the Python libraries to be imported are given as arguments to the Dynamic Library `DynLib`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DynLib    lib1    lib2

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${returnvalue}    Scrabble Is Fun
    log to console    ${returnvalue}
    ${returnvalue}    Books Are Great
    log to console    ${returnvalue}
```

This is the first library: `lib1.py`

```
class lib1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def scrabble_is_fun(self):
        return "It is Super Fun!"
    def rummicub_is_fun(self):
        return "It is more fun than Scrabble"
```

This is the first library: `lib2.py`

```
class lib2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass    
    def books_are_great(self):
        return "reading is good for the soul"
    def music_is_wonderful(self):
        return "listening is entertaining"
```

This is the Dynamic Library `DynLib` that loads the names of the keywords of all the lib names provided. Then when a keyword is run, it seeks the first library with given keyword name as a method and executes it.

```
class DynLib(object):

    def __init__(self, *libList):
        self.libraries = libList

    def get_keyword_names(self):
        returnval = []

        for libName in self.libraries:
            module = __import__(libName)
            instance = getattr(module, libName)()
            keywords = [x for x in dir(instance) if not x.startswith('_')]
            returnval = list(set(returnval) | set(keywords))

        return returnval

    def run_keyword(self, name, args):
        name.replace(" ", "_")

        for libName in self.libraries:
            module = __import__(libName)
            instance = getattr(module, libName)()
            method_name = getattr(instance , name, None)

            if callable(method_name):
                return method_name()
```

A little disclaimer. The above code does not do any checking if the class ran is indeed one that is allowed to be run. Having these kinds of polymorphic classes is a security risk for which appropriate mitigation needs to be in place.

It also has no support for variables, arguments or kwargs, although building it in would not be hard.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and  I have one more doubt on this. Here your example two libraries are using inside single library contains single class.   suppose single library contains multiple classes. how to call in robot framework. and also how to run that library in as a remote server.  Thanks

Comment: With respect to starting the Python Remote Server I'd like to refer you to the link provided in the answer to the [Python Remote Server documentation](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer). In addition can you clarify what you mean with 'single library contains multiple classes'. In my mind a library is nothing more than a Python class with specific methods. Importing other classes in a Library class is common place and thus I don't see any problem.